# Why does Old Norse ‘Óláfr’ have á instead of ei?

Tags: etymology, proto-germanic, old-norse

The Proto-Germanic (PG) diphthong **ai* generally becomes *ei* in Old Norse (ON), except regularly before an original **h* and commonly before *r* (but only from PG **r*, not from rhotacised PG **z*).

Examples are easy to find:

- PG *stainaz* > ON *steinn* ‘stone’
- PG *hlaiƀaz* > ON *hleifr* ‘loaf’
- PG *taihwō* > ON *tá* ‘toe’
- PG *maiza-* > ON *meir-* ‘more’

But the name *Óláfr* < PG **Anu-laiƀaz* ‘ancestral inheritor’ (or something like that) is an odd exception. The PG **ai* comes before **ƀ*, so we’d expect ON *ei* as the outcome.

To be sure, the form *Óleifr* does exist as a variant, but *Óláfr* is by far the more common of the two. Oddly, the simplex form (without the prefix **anu-*) is exclusively *Leifr*, both as a common noun and as a proper name.

So why does this particular word have this unexpected vowel?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet see p. 40 (section 117.8) in Heusler 1921 https://archive.org/details/altislndischesel00heus/page/40/mode/2up

Comment: @AlexB. Well, that seems to work at least some of the time, though cases like _Þórsteinn_ don’t fit (there’s no _*Þórstánn_ as far as I know). You should add that as an answer.

Comment: Wait a second, *Olivia* is not from*Olaf* and instead it means *olive*? You have got to be kidding me. As far as I can tell, there is simply hypochrostic folk etymology at play, probably contaminated with 'love'. See *Johann Lafer*, wherever that name is from. Cp. [Laffrenzen](http://www.namenforschung.net/id/name/159271/1) vel sim. from the Saint *Laurentius*, see also *Franz*, *Frank*.